# teamcity git hosted in IIS access issue

Tags: git, teamcity

I am trying to access my git repo hosted under IIS with Windows Authentication enabled.

When i specify the username like domain\username the connection fails. 
From the stack trace it looks like the error is due to the way the network username is given. How else can we give the windows auth user which has domain in them.

This works fine from the console when i do a git clone  ( https:/domain\user@mydomain.com/xyz/)

**Error details**

Test connection failed in Git Repo:: Git Repo. List remote refs failed: 
java.net.ConnectException: Cannot determine proxy for ....

**Stacktrace**

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https:/domain\user@mydomain.com/xyz/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:276)
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:523)
at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getRemoteRefs(GitVcsSupport.java:503)
... 44 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Cannot determine proxy for https:/domain\user@mydomain.com/xyz/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.proxyFor(HttpSupport.java:196)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen(TransportHttp.java:475)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen(TransportHttp.java:471)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:422)
... 47 more

**Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https:/domain\user@mydomain.com/xyz/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack**
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.proxyFor(HttpSupport.java:193)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your URL.

You have

```
https:/domain\user@mydomain.com/xyz/
```

instead of

```
https://domain\user@mydomain.com/xyz/
```